Issue with digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure Docker Compose Setup – Transaction Simulation Failure
I’m encountering an error while running the Docker Compose setup from the Metaplex digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure repository. I’d appreciate any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue.
Issue Details
Repository: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/digital-asset-rpc-infrastructure
Service: load-1 within Docker Compose setup
Error:
The Docker Compose run fails with a Result::unwrap() call on an Err value. Specifically, there is a RpcError related to transaction simulation.
Error message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x1
It appears that there are insufficient lamports for the transaction, with the available amount being 35,960, while 2,039,280 lamports are required.
Logs (summarized for readability):
These are the logs of the load service -->
load-1  | called Result::unwrap() on an Err value: Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x1", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(2, Custom(1))), logs: Some(["Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [1]", "Program log: Instruction: InitializeMint", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2967 of 799850 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program log: Create", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 1622 of 788490 compute units", "Program return: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA pQAAAAAAAAA=", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]", "Transfer: insufficient lamports 35960, need 2039280", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 failed: custom program error: 0x1", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 13014 of 796883 compute units", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: custom program error: 0x1"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(16131), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) }
load-1  | note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
